# Tags for questions about superseded C++ technical specifications such as Concepts TS

Tags: discussion, tags

There are questions with the tag [c++-concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-concepts) that are really about the C++ concepts TS. That can be confusing because there are constructs in C++ concepts TS that are not valid in C++20 constraints and concepts such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58394556/c-concepts-can-i-have-a-constraint-requiring-a-function-be-present-in-a-clas).

Should there be a [c++-concepts-ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-concepts-ts) tag for the questions referring to the concepts TS, so that [c++-concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-concepts) will be for C++ concepts as they exist in C++ proper?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure having tags for every TS is useful. The [tag:c++-ts] tag could be added to the linked question, and questions that are about the TS for some particular feature (as has already been added for a couple of questions about the TS version of concepts).

Comment: TS = *technical specification* (not [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript) - in this context).